# Is it possible to send a notification that displays a timer/stopwatch on IOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, background-process

I am currently developing a timer app in react native. My app has a stopwatch that users can start and stop. Now i want users to be able to see the current time of the stopwatch by constantly updating a notification, even when the app is not open. This requires the task to run in the background, but I learned that IOS only allows apps to run for 30 seconds in the background.

I know there are some workarounds with using GPS or bluetooth every 30 seconds to extend it, but I was wondering if there are any other ways I could consider. Thank you!